# Two equivalent definitions of almost sure convergence of random variables.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1,2,\cdots}$ is a sequence of random variables. There are equivalent definitions of almost sure convergence of random variables. How can one prove the equivalence?

> $\mathbb{P}[\omega:\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)] = 1 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}[\omega:\sup_{k>n}|X_k(\omega) - X(\omega)|>\epsilon] = 0$

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963380/).

Answer (score 11):

The former implies
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=& P(\lim_{i\to\infty}X_i \neq X\,  \text{or} \lim_{i\to\infty}X_i \, \text{does not exists}) \\
&=& P(\omega:\exists n\in\mathbf{N}, \forall m\in\mathbf{N}, \exists i>m \,\,\,  \text{s.t.} \,\, |X_i(\omega) - X(\omega)| < 1/n)\\
&=& P(\bigcup_n \bigcap_m \bigcup_{i>m} \{\omega:|X_i(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\})\\
&\overset{\forall n}{\ge}& P(\bigcap_m \bigcup_{i>m} \{\omega:|X_i(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\})\\
&=&P(\limsup_{i\to\infty} \{\omega:|X_i(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\}) \\
&=&P(\lim_{i\to\infty} \sup_{j > i}\{\omega:|X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\})\\
&=&\lim_{i\to\infty} P(\sup_{j > i}\{\omega:|X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\}) \ge 0.\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The last line is justified by continuity of measures from above (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29#Properties)). Now let's prove the converse. For some $n\in\mathbf{N}$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
0&=&\lim_{i\to\infty} P(\sup_{j > i}\{\omega:|X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\})\\
&=&P(\lim_{i\to\infty} \sup_{j > i}\{\omega:|X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\})\\
&=&P(\limsup_{i\to\infty} \{\omega:|X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\})\\
&=&P(\bigcap_i\bigcup_{j>i} \{\omega:|X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n\})\\
&=&P(\omega:\forall i, \exists j>i, \text{s.t.}\, |X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge 1/n)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
This implies, for each $n$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& P(\omega: \exists i, \forall j>i, \text{s.t.}\, |X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| < 1/n)\\
&=&P(\omega:\lim_{i\to\infty}|X_j(\omega) - X(\omega)| = 0)\\
&=&P(\omega:\lim_{i\to\infty}X_j(\omega) = X(\omega))
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Actually, I think this proof may need to be polished. But I hope it is not wrong in a bird's eye view at least.

Comment: shouldn't the second line be $\ge 1/n$ instead of $<1/n$?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's denote by $Y_n$ the variable $\sup_{k>n} |X_k - X|$. Observe that

1. $(Y_n)$ is a *decreasing* sequence of nonnegative random variables
2. $Y_n \to 0$ iff $X_n \to X$
3. "$\mathsf{P}\{Y_n > \epsilon\} \to 0$ for all $\epsilon$" means that $Y_n \to 0$ in probability

Now everything follows from the simple but useful fact: if a $(Y_n)$ is a *monotone* sequence, then its convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence (that the converse is true for *any* sequence is an extremely standard fact). This can be proved by different means, but the easiest proof that I know of is as follows:

Any monotone sequence converges (almost surely) to *something* (this is just standard calculus, and "almost surely" is actually irrelevant). Hence it also converges in probability to the same limit, hence if $Y_n \to Y$ in probability, then $Y$ must coincide with the almost sure limit.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote the probability space by the triple: $(\Omega, \mathbb{A}, \mathbb{P})$.

First we prove the former implies the latter:
Let us denote by $E$ the event that the sequence converges. That is: 
$$E \triangleq \{w \in \Omega | \lim_{n}Y_n(\omega) = Y(\omega)\} \in \mathbb{A} $$
Almost sure convergence implies that $\mathbb{P}(E) = 1$ (by definition of a.s. convergence).
We have:
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}\left[\left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\}\right]= \\ 
&\mathbb{P}\left[\left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\} \cap E \right] + \mathbb{P}\left[\left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\} \cap E^C \right] \leq \\
&\mathbb{P}\left[\left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\} \cap E \right] 
\end{align}
(In the last equality we applied monotonicity of measure and that $\mathbb{P}(E^C)=0$ ).

Continuity of measure from above (see:[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Measure_(mathematics)&oldid=907712470)) implies we can take limits into probability measures:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n}\left( \mathbb{P}\left[\left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\} \cap E \right] \right)= \\
&\mathbb{P}\left[\lim_{n} \left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\} \cap E \right]=\mathbb{P}(\Phi) = 0 
\end{align}
Now we prove the latter implies the former. This is, again, easy by the  continuity of measure from above. Let $E$ be defined as above. We have:
\begin{align} 
0 &=\lim_{n}\left( \mathbb{P}\left[\left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\} \right] \right) \\ 
&= \mathbb{P}\left[\lim_{n}\left\{w\in\Omega\middle| \sup_{k \geq n} |Y_k(\omega)-Y(\omega)|> \epsilon\right\} \right] = \mathbb{P}(E^c)
\end{align}
Where the first equality is continuity of measure and the last equality is just the definition of limits. Hence $P(E)=1$ as desired.